# Await not working as expected with JS mysql package

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, async-await

I am pretty new to Javascript/node and do not yet understand the concept. The following below code is unclear to me. I want "END" not to show before I have retrieved all results from the database. I hope you will not tell me to put it behind the rows output and there is really a solution for the problem. I thought "await" will make the code really wait for its processing to finish.

```
const mysql = require('mysql'); // or use import if you use TS
const util = require('util');
const conn = mysql.createConnection({
    "host"     : "",
    "user"     : "",
    "password" : "",
    "database" : "",
});

// node native promisify
const query = util.promisify(conn.query).bind(conn);

(async () => {
  try {
    const rows = await query('select count(*) as count from table');
    console.log(rows);
  } finally {
    conn.end();
  }
})()

console.log("END");
```

Thanks

Comment: await only works with Promise, you can't wait for another thing

Comment: I though the promisfy does that for me.

Comment: Move `console.log("END")` to the line after the finally block or put it inside the finally block.

Comment: `await` makes the code below it inside the async function code wait for the Promise to resolve. It doesn't magically affect code that has already run.

Comment: Okay but my question was how to do it without doing this. Because in general I have pretty much simplified the question becuase in general its more complex where a class must be initialized with values from the DB and I do not want other code to run while its doing that.

Comment: You need to *embrace* the async programming concept. Keep awaiting promises to resolve before doing the next thing. If you don't do that consistently, you'll get the effect you have now.

Comment: You can't prevent other code from running while waiting for a Promise to resolve. Instead, you can write that other code so that it also waits for the Promise to resolve.

Comment: Don't have async code running in a class constructor. Instead await the async result and only *then* create your class instance.

Comment: Okay I understand but I cant really get my head around it. In the real code I have a class with an init method that initialized class attributes from the DB. Outside of the class I want to call doSomething on that class and it must wait until the attributes are initialized, it seems very odd for me now that outside of the class I now have to hand out the promise to be able to know when I may call doSomething

Comment: trincot's answer seems like it could solve my problem. I will to implement it that way.

Comment: @trincot is the pattern to choose here to read the mysql values and then pass them into the constructor?

Comment: Yes, indeed, that is how it would work. But we are discussing things here that are not in your question, so I cannot really post an answer ;-)

Answer (score -2):

You cannot use it like that. Without a callback mysql will stream the results instead and you need to use the `on` event listener.

As per the docs:

> You MUST NOT provide a callback to the query() method when streaming rows.

So the way you have it, you need to add events and resolve a promise:

```
async function myQueryFunction(str, replacements) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    let rows = []
    query(str, replacements)
      .on('result', (row) => {
        // Do something with the row
        rows.push(row)
      })
      .on('end', () => resolve(rows))
  })
}
```

Otherwise you need to call the `query` method with a callback, so create a query function that resolves a promise...

```
async function myQueryFunction(str, replacements) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    query(str, replacements, (err, rows) => {
      resolve(rows)
    })
  })
}
```

Finally you can call your method that was created from one of the above examples like this:

```
(async () => {
  try {
    const rows = await myQueryFunction('select count(*) as count from table');
    console.log(rows);
  } finally {
    conn.end();
  }
})()
```